The paths in the basic configuration inherited by the extends property in jsconfig.json will be overwritten by the paths in the current configuration
This is the basic configuration
// baseJsconfig.json
{
  paths: {
    "@coms/*": ["../../components/*"]
 }
}

This is the project configuration
// jsconfig.json
{
 "extends": "./baseJsconfig.json",
  paths: {
    "@/*": ["src/*"]
 }
}

The actual output is as follows
// jsconfig.json
{
  paths: {
    "@/*": ["src/*"]
 }
}

But my expected result is like the following, how should it be written?
// jsconfig.json
{
  paths: {
    "@/*": ["src/*"],
    "@coms/*": ["../../components/*"]
 }
}

